# PHP variable caching

Tags: php, hosting, eaccelerator

I have some data in MySQL database that are static most of the time. They are mainly almost static values like cities, states, and ethnic. I want to cache them in a variable, preferebly in memory, so that I won't need to perform another query to MySQL every time a page loads.

The problem is, my hosting doesn't support memcache nor APC. The only accelerator I could find is eAccelerator, and I don't think it will do what I have in mind.

Is there any way I can do caching? It is http://www.k-disk.net

Thank you

Comment: what about putting them in a file? MySQL, does do some caching on its own.

Comment: yeah, you could just declare them as PHP arrays if they *never* change and stick them in a file somewhere.

Comment: they are not "never" change, but they are hardly change. New cities, new areas, sometimes new names. Kind like few years in between. Data like that are only a waste of resource if you query them again and again, and come up with the very same answer for a few years straight, no matter where your query ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Shared Memory extension.

Look this basic sample: http://www.php.net/manual/en/shmop.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 3):

> Caching is a great example of the ubiquitous time-space tradeoff in
>   programming. You can save time by using space to store results. [[1]](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/)

There are many ways at many levels to implement cache on a website. Lets look at them starting form the front end and moving towards the backend without getting into too much details.

### HTTP caching

See [How To Optimize Your Site With HTTP Caching](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/)

### Application level caching

This is caching of "expensive to query" database objects.
Eg: memcache, caching pages in files etc.

### Op-code cache

Eg: PHP accelerator, eAccelerator etc.

### Database level cache

Optimizing the database by tuning its parameters based on the need and machine hardware.

In your case, I would recommend tweaking around with my.cnf since given enough RAM, MySQL is quite fast. Just try not to pre-optimize.

Comment: I don't think I got access to my.cnf :D Yes, MySQL is quite fast, but will MySQL keep that data in memory when we deal with other data? And querying MySQL for something so small and that won't change in few years period I think is a waste of resources. I plan to store them in memory. Maybe only a few MB of RAM, and stays there forever. Kind like singleton in Java. My goal is to avoid unnecessary IO cost, and keep them in memory.

Comment: Well, unless you are getting tons of hits everyday which adversely affects other parts of your site, I wouldn't really spend much time in optimizing it to that extent. You know what they say about premature optimization :)

Comment: Well, it's kind of my habit to always write any application like that :). So I am kind of lost when they told me that they don't have any persistent caching. It's mostly static anyway, and PHP read data from disk or cache on every page request.

Answer (score 2):

You could just write a file to your server that saves a serialized php array of variables. Just plug all of your variables into an associative array then serialize and save. Though I honestly don't see why you don't save the variables to a variable table in the database. Its not an expensive operation.

```
$myvars = array(
  'how_high_do_i_jump' => 10,
  'which_tv_show_is_best' => 'Glee',
  'enable_caching' => true,
  'mathematical_solution' => 4534.234
);

$file_str = serialize($myvars);

//Save the file
file_put_contents('myvars.ser', $myvars);

//To reverse just do this
$file = file_get_contents('myvars.ser');

$myvars = unserialize($file);
```

If that doesn't work for you there is a way to get memcache on your shared host if you have SSH access. I actually did this on hostmonster. Here is a walk through on it (though this is not the article I originally used).
http://andrewpeng.net/posts/2011/06/271273-memcached-and-dreamhost-shared-tutorial.html

Comment: Then I would need to read disk every time user ask for this page. Kind like report, or geographical data. My goal is to eliminate this at all, so I only need to query mmy object in memory. As I said, something like singleton in Java that serves static hash.

Comment: I am not aware of any such construct in PHP. But maybe there is and someone else can tell us about it.

Comment: memcached or apc could do my trick, but they they are not available. So I am actually looking for a replacement.

Comment: Do you have SSH access? If you do then the link I posted above will tell you how to add memcache to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom cache class storing and reading data from disk, using file_put_contents() and file_get_contents().

Comment: I want to avoid any kind unnecessary IO cost. And saving to disk won't help that problem. I am looking something that can preserve those values in RAM between all pages, and PHP only need to find those value in RAM. It is not that big, and it won't change for few years anyway.